# ReduxForm inside Modal

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I use ReactJS and want to add reduxForm to modal.
For modal I use [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) library that represents bootstrap 4 for React.
For form validation I use [reduxForm](https://redux-form.com/6.0.5/)

I have tasked add form  modal with validation fields and I did that:

```
  render() {
    const {handleSubmit, fields: {
            email
        }} = this.props;

    const FormEmail = ({touched, error}) => {
        if (touched && error)
            return (
                <div>
                    <Input type="email" name="email" id="email"/>
                    <div className="error">{error}</div>
                </div>
            );
        return (<Input type="email" name="email" id="email"/>);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Col>
                <Col xs={{
                    size: 9
                }}>
                    <ReportSettings/>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={{
                    size: 3
                }}>
                    <Button outline color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Share</Button>
                </Col>
            </Col>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.toggle)}>
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Share</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <CheckBoxInputField data={this.state.measurements} handleFieldChange={this.handleFieldChange}/>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label for="email" xs={2}>Email</Label>
                            <Col xs={10}>
                                <FormEmail {...email}/>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label for="message" xs={2}>Message</Label>
                            <Col xs={10}>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="message" id="message"/>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>

                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button action="submit" color="primary" value={true}>OK</Button>
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle} value={false}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

my toggle function:

```
toggle(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        });
        if (e.target.value === 'true') {
            const measurementsID = this.state.measurements.values.filter((measurement) => {
                return measurement.checked;
            }).map((measurement) => {
                return measurement.value;
            });

            this.props.onShare(MeasurementsToBitMap(measurementsID));
        }
    }
```

validation function:

```
function validate(formProps) {
    const errors = {};

    if (!formProps.email) {
        errors.email = 'Please enter an email';
    }
    return errors;
}
```

finally I export Component:

```
export default reduxForm({form: 'form', fields: ['email'], validate})(HeadMeasurement);
```

When I click on **cancel button** the modal close it works good, but when I click on **OK button** 
and fields aren't valid error messages aren't showed otherwise when fields are valid modal isn't disappeared.

My question is how to combine reduxForm and Modal work together?

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: What version of reactstrap and redux form are you using?

Comment: "redux-form": "^5.0.1", "reactstrap": "^3.2.2", "react": "^15.3.1",

Answer (score 2):

reactstrap inserts your modal definition at the bottom of the rendered html doc so wrapping `<Form>` around `<Modal>` doesn't work. You have to have your  inside the . In your case since you are doing a submit action you will want it wrapped around both your footer and the body tags.

```
           <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.toggle)}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Share</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <CheckBoxInputField data={this.state.measurements} handleFieldChange={this.handleFieldChange}/>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label for="email" xs={2}>Email</Label>
                            <Col xs={10}>
                                <FormEmail {...email}/>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label for="message" xs={2}>Message</Label>
                            <Col xs={10}>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="message" id="message"/>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>

                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button action="submit" color="primary" value={true}>OK</Button>
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle} value={false}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Form>
            </Modal>
```

Also, did you bind your toggle to this in your constructor?

```
constructor(props) {
  this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}
```

Alternatively, use arrow functions.

```
toggle = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    modal: !this.state.modal
  });
  ...
}
```

Comment: how to destroy the form once it is submitted

Comment: @Nidhinkumar I think you're looking for `destroyOnUnmount: true` [docs here](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-destroyonunmount-boolean-code-optional-)